# Is it possible to access a live audio stream in the browser?

Tags: webrtc, twilio

I want to write a web app for people who are deaf by allowing them to type as a way to talk in a phone call. The goal is to allow deaf people to enter phone number in a web page, initiate a phone call, transcribe voice of the receiving end into text in real time, and convert the text of the responding end into voice in real time.

I plan to use Twilio to make the call, capture the audio stream, use speech recognition API to transcribe the voice, and use the text-to-speech function of Twilio to convert the text.

I know Twilio doesn't have the capability to do real-time transcription and I can't seem to find a way to access the audio stream through the twilio.connection object. Therefore I am thinking about using the Media Capture API to capture that voice. Is that possible?

Comment: This is a bit broad for a question on StackOverflow. With the media capture API you get access to tracks in a user's [media stream](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#mediastreamtrack) and with WebRTC you can get hold of those tracks on the incoming mediastream that you receive in a connection.

Comment: @philnash I just expanded the question to more details. I am reading the WebRTC spec right now. It seems like I should be able to get access to the audio stream through the MediaStreamTrack object? Please let me know if I should provide more details.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this example](https://github.com/szimek/webrtc-translate). It doesn't use Twilio, but it does use WebRTC and speech recognition to do (almost) real time language translation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible . But there might be some browser dependency . [Simple](https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example) example can be found here . The code would be something like this.

```
   var constraints = {
        video: true,
        audio: true,
    };

    if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);
    } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is accessible via Twilio Device api

`Twilio.Device.activeConnection().mediaStream`